# np.insert error in numpy version '1.13.3'

Tags: numpy, insert

I try to insert specific values in an array at given indices, with the use of `np.insert`. Before I used Numpy 1.12 and the code was running fine but with the new Numpy 1.13.3 the following error occurs

```
ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape () could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape ()
```

My Code:

```
intial_array= 1D numpy array
indices= 1D numpy array
values_to_insert= 1D numpy array

mt_new2=np.insert(intial_array, indices,values_to_insert)
```

Is this problem known or does someone knows how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can't you show us the problem arrays?  `shape ()` indicates that they are small.  My guess is that they have tighten up edge condition.  Show full error traceback.

Comment: The arrays are quite big, so it it difficult to show them, the individual shapes are (125000L,) (19600L,) (4L,)

Comment: How many insertion indices, and how many values?

Comment: indices values 19600, and values 4 I always wanted to insert the complete array, now I modified indices and values in such a way that they have the same shape and the problem is solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Early `numpy` can replicate `values` as needed to fit the index size:

```
>>> x = numpy.arange(10)
>>> numpy.insert(x,[1,3,4,5],[10,20])
array([ 0, 10,  1,  2, 20,  3, 10,  4, 20,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
>>> numpy.__version__
'1.12.0'
```

New numpy expects matching size:

```
In [81]: x = np.arange(10)

In [82]: np.insert(x, [1,3,4,5],[10,20])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-82-382864de5db0> in <module>()
----> 1 np.insert(x, [1,3,4,5],[10,20])

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in insert(arr, obj, values, axis)
   5085     slobj[axis] = indices
   5086     slobj2[axis] = old_mask
-> 5087     new[slobj] = values
   5088     new[slobj2] = arr
   5089 

ValueError: shape mismatch: value array of shape (2,) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (4,)

In [83]: np.insert(x, [1,3,4,5],[10,20,10,20])
Out[83]: array([ 0, 10,  1,  2, 20,  3, 10,  4, 20,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

It looks like the earlier version used `resize`, explicitly or implicitly,

```
In [85]: np.insert(x, [1,3,4,5],np.resize([10,20,30],4))
Out[85]: array([ 0, 10,  1,  2, 20,  3, 30,  4, 10,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```